# Decoding and encoding JSON in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I was following some django rest framework tutorials and found some obscure codes. This snippet is from the customised user model, the project from which uses jwt for authentication.

As I commented in the snippet, I can't notice the reason Why they first encodes data and decode it again. I thought this kind of pattern is not only specific to this tutorial, but quite a general pattern. Could anyone explain me please?

```
 def _generate_jwt_token(self):
        """
        Generates a JSON Web Token that stores this user's ID and 
        has an expiry date set to 60 days into the future.
        """
        dt = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=60)


        token = jwt.encode({ #first encode here
            'id': self.pk,
            'exp': int(dt.strftime('%s'))
        }, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithm='HS256')

        return token.decode('utf-8') #returns decoded object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*“Encoding”* usually refers to converting data to its binary representation (bytes).

JWT *(JSON Web Token)* encoding uses a specific data structure and cryptographic signing to allow secure, authenticated exchanges.

The steps to encode data as *JWT* are as follows :

1. The *payload* is converted to json and encoded using base64.
2. A *header*, specifying the *token type* (eg. `jwt`) and the *signature algorithm* to use (eg. `HS256`), is encoded similarly.
3. A *signature* is derived from your private key and the two previous values.
4. Result is obtained by joining header, payload and signature with dots. The output is a **binary string**.

*More informations [here](https://jwt.io/introduction/).*

Decoding it using UTF-8 transforms this binary string into an Unicode string :

```
>>> encoded_bin = jwt.encode({'some': 'data'}, 'secret_sig', algorithm='HS256')
>>> type(encoded_bin)
<class 'bytes'>

>>> encoded_string = encoded_bin.decode('utf-8')
>>> type(encoded_string)
<class 'str'>
```

---

Notes:

- It is not always possible to decode bytes to string. Base64-encoding your data allows you to store any bytes as a text representation, but the encoded form requires more space (+33%) than it's raw representation.
- A binary string is prefixed by a `b` in your Python interpreter (eg. `b"a binary string"`)

Comment: Please correct your answer. Encoding and encrypting are two different things! Nothing get's encrypted here. The header and payload of a JWT/JWS are only base64url encoded and the signature is a hash, that also no encryption.

Comment: @jps Edited. I didn't know about jwt, I assumed wrongly looking a the code provided by the author. Thanks

Comment: I don't see 'encryption' mentioned in the question. Your edit is also not correct. The signature is not a hash of the secret key, but a hash of header and payload. You should only answer, when you know the subject.